# Error while trying to login using facebook Scrumptious

Tags: iphone, facebook, ios6

While trying to login using facebook Scrumptious, it is showing the following error, Where should i want to the facebook id?

```
2013-02-16 14:23:21.283 roulocalapp[2378:c07] Application tried to push a nil view 
controller on target <UINavigationController: 0x945b180>.
2013-02-16 14:23:21.288 roulocalapp[2378:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
exception 'com.facebook.sdk:InvalidOperationException', reason: 'FBSession: No AppID 
provided; either pass an AppID to init, or add a string valued key with the appropriate
id    named FacebookAppID to the bundle *.plist'
```

[image]

Comment: Did you add your AppID in *.plist ?

Comment: yeah i did like this FacebookAppID: <fbid>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow these steps to fix your issue:

open your project in Xcode.

Find yourprojectname.plist file in your supported files.

Add an entry called 'FacebookAppID' and set its value as 'fb12786126112789' (use your app id preceded by 'fb')

Add a URL Types, make sure it is a dictionary, at Item 0, Add 'URL Schemes' and add a string in it which should be your app id - similar to this 'fb12786126112789'  (make sure it should start with fb').

Comment: In your application plist file.

Comment: Should i want to add anywhere else

Comment: Remove the build, clean all targets and then run the application again. Also share the screenshot of your plist file with us.

Comment: How did you fix it? I'm getting the same error and can't really fix it!

Comment: 'FacebookAppID' value should not be prefixed with'fb. Please read the tutorial for details.

Comment: @Zorayr - at that time it was prefixed with 'fb', not in the recent SDK's anymore.

Comment: Makes sense @Reno, you probably want to either delete your answer to update it? Otherwise, it will confuse developers encountering this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found out that I had a space at the end of FacebookAppID since I copy pasted the name. My .plist key was, 'FacebookAppID ' - double check that your key does not contain any spaces.